# What is the Ruby terminology for this part of an iterator?

Tags: ruby, iterator

I am trying to understand what the name for |n| is in the code below.

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.map { |n| n * 2 }
# [2, 4, 6]
```

I know what it does and how it works, but is it called a 'placeholder' or does it have an official name (maybe 'iterator')? I would like to know as it will help me remember it and discuss my code better.

Comment: Block argument list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, since ruby takes from Smalltalk this makes sense

Comment: It's not an iterator, it's the current item under iteration. The *general* term is "parameter" or "argument" list. It can be narrowed down as Jon says since it's the argument list to a block in this case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's a block parameter list, actually. Parameter == a hole left in the definition. Argument == what you use to fill in the hole. Some languages also call them formal argument / actual argument or formal parameter / actual parameter. If I want to be really pedantic and at the same time clearly be understood by all different communities, I will say formal parameter / actual argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRuby's parser ([`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_5/parse.y#L3075)) calls it `block_param_def` (*block parameters definition*). You're defining the parameters of a block after all.

In “The Ruby Programming Language” by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto it's called *block parameters* too (5.4.1 Block Syntax, page 141):

> Blocks can be parameterized, just as methods can. Block parameters are separated with commas and delimited with a pair of vertical bar (`|`) characters […]

A *block argument* would be `&blk` as in `def foo(&blk)` where `blk` will refer to a block - which is usually anonymous - if one is passed as part of a method call. An important difference the book also mentions in a footnote (6.4.5 Block Arguments, page 190):

> - We use the term “block argument” instead of “block parameter” for method parameters prefixed with `&`. This is because the phrase “block parameter” refers to the parameter list (such as `|x|`) of the block itself.

Arguably a bit odd and not really logical as arguments to a block (such as `1`, `2` and `3` in your example) could be called block arguments too.

Comment: The general difference between a parameter and an argument is that a parameter is part of a method (or block) definition to specify what can be passed in. The "thing" passed in to a specific call is the arguments which are then mapped to the defined method parameters. When talking about block arguments, you are thus referring to a block being passed as an argument to a method call. With block parameters on the other hand, you are specifying the parameters a block can take when it is called. Since defined parameters and given arguments usually match, these terms are often used interchangeably.

Comment: "When talking about block arguments, you are thus referring to a block being passed as an argument to a method call" – Or to the arguments passed to a block call. Isn't English fun? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Item would be a good description. If you check out the Ruby documentation for the [.map method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-map), you'll see that it is described as {|item| block }. So within the pipe's (|) is the "item" then next come the code block.